# How does computer decide the length of an opcode?

Tags: assembly, opcode

Length of opcodes are variable. So, What is the mechanism computer uses to decide where the current opcode finishes exactly?

Comment: The *vast majority* of architectures do not use variable-length opcodes. In fact, the only one that I can think of which does is x86.

Comment: @CodyGray in fact most modern architectures have a variable-length instruction variant: MIPS, ARM, PowerPC, [ForwardCom](https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=801), RISC-V, SuperH...